# xenix (sysv) file system doesn't support since kernel 2.1.21

Tags: filesystems, kernel, partition, partition-table

xenix filesystem equvalent sysv filesystem, man mount says:

> Note that,cohorent, sysv and  xenix are equvalent and that xenix amd cohorent will be removed at some point in future use sysv instead.

According to [Old Unix and old partition table](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228528/old-unix-and-old-partition-table) I need to read a Xenix (sysv) filesystem. 
Do you have any soolution , Read via netbsd , or FreeBD? 
Or can I load xe xenix module?

Answer (score 2):

What it says is that the xenix, coherent, and sysv filesystems are supported by the same drivers. The filesystems are similar enough that having separate drivers is just a waste of time and effort.

As such, you should mount it with sysv as the filesystem type. That *should* just work.

Comment: I tested with `-t xenix` and `-t sysv`  But I didn't get answer.

Comment: Do you know to how mount it?

Comment: Should be with `-t sysv`. However, your kernel also requires support for that. Check that it has it; your configuration (often found in `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` or `/proc/config.gz`) should have the option `CONFIG_SYSV_FS` set to `y` or `m`. If it is the latter, you may need to load the correct module.

Comment: refer to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229652/sysv-and-unknown-partition-table