# sysv and unknown partition table?

Tags: filesystems, mount, partition, hard-disk, disk

We have disk about 1985, It has a Unix.But we didn't know type of Unix.I did the following step :

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of./all_of_disk.iso #sdc is the given disk
```

Then :

```
hexdump -C all_of_disk.iso > hex.dump

grep -i sysv hex.dump 
00000000  53 59 53 56 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |SYSV............|
000ea4a0  00 00 53 59 53 56 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..SYSV..........|
00651130  5f 67 74 73 79 73 76 2e  6f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |_gtsysv.o.......|
00652000  00 00 02 00 67 74 73 79  73 76 00 00 00 00 13 5c  |....gtsysv.....\|
00652010  00 01 00 00 02 00 63 70  73 79 73 76 00 00 00 00  |......cpsysv....|
00652580  65 6e 5f 73 79 73 76 5f  63 6f 75 6e 74 00 6f 70  |en_sysv_count.op|
00652590  65 6e 5f 73 79 73 76 5f  66 69 72 73 74 00 6f 70  |en_sysv_first.op|
006525a0  65 6e 5f 73 79 73 76 5f  6c 61 73 74 00 72 65 74  |en_sysv_last.ret|
007101c0  00 00 53 59 53 56 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..SYSV..........|
```

Note: First word of data is SYSV.

```
zgrep -i sysv /proc/config.gz 
CONFIG_SYSVIPC=y
CONFIG_SYSVIPC_SYSCTL=y
CONFIG_SYSV68_PARTITION=y
CONFIG_SYSVIPC_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_SYSV_FS=y
```

My disk:

```
fdisk -l  ./all_of_disk.iso 
Disk ./all_of_disk.iso: 550.5 MiB, 577241088 bytes, 1127424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

parted   ./all_of_disk.iso  print
Error: /home/mohsen/all_of_disk.iso: unrecognised disk label
Model:  (file)                                                            
Disk /home/mohsen/all_of_disk.iso: 577MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Question: We need to mount this disk, but I get the following error:

```
mount -o loop -t sysv ./all_of_disk.iso ./x/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please post the output of: `zgrep -i iso9660`, and then try `mount -o loop -t iso9660 ./all_of_disk.iso ./x/`

Comment: Do you have support for mounting a UNIX V7 filesystem?

Comment: Why using `mount -o loop` instead of mounting with `-r`?

Comment: @schily , yes If you read my post , I put `CONFIG_SYSV_FS=y`

Comment: @eyoung100 , Why iso9660? It's related to cd-drive, I got dd from disk.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi , I get with `-r` and `-o loop` and `dmesg`  print for both : `VFS: unable to find oldfs superblock on device loop0`

Comment: When people write sysv, they today usually think of SVr4 and the default filesystem for SVr4 is UFS. Do you get support for a V7 filesystem when you configure Linux with sysv?